# Use query data from Firebase Realtime DB as input for another function

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

So I'm using Firebase Realtime Database to store some data and would like to use the results of a query, as an input for another function (generate signed URLs). My code is as follows:

```
// initialize the empty list
let lista = []

// define the async function that does everything
async function queryandgeturls() {
    // make the query to the firebase realtimeDB
    await ref.orderByChild('timestamp_start').startAt(timestamp1).endAt(timestamp2).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        lista.push(snapshot.val().name);
    });

    // use the list as input for another function to get Signed URLs
    for (const fileName of lista) {
        const [signedUrl] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).getSignedUrl({
            version: 'v4',
            expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000,
            action: 'read'
        });
        console.log(`The signed URL for ${fileName} is ${signedUrl}`);
    }
};

// call the function
queryandgeturls().catch(console.error);
```

No luck so far. Any leads?

Comment: Where are you trying to use them? You can simply call the 2nd function from there and pass them as parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on` method keeps an open listener to the event that can be called repeatedly, so it doesn't return a promise (since a promise can only resolve once). So the `await ref.orderByChild....on('child_added'...` in your code doesn't do anything, which probably explains the problem.

To properly solve this problem, use `once('value', ...` and don't combine `await` and callbacks.

```
async function queryandgeturls() {
    // make the query to the firebase realtimeDB
    const results = await ref.orderByChild('timestamp_start').startAt(timestamp1).endAt(timestamp2).once('value');
    results.forEach((snapshot) => {
        lista.push(snapshot.val().name);
    });
    ...
```